# Правильная работа с COM объектами в .NET

Tags: c#, .net, com

Работаю с `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`, так как он производительнее ADO.NET при работе с Access и меня интересует следующее:

1. Имеет ли смысл присваивать null объектам, которые я больше не хочу использовать? Слышал, что .NET подсчитывает ссылки и после этого автоматически убивает объект.
2. Достаточно ли закрыть RecordSet и т п объекты или нужно после этого вызвать один из `Marshal` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первому вопросу:

Если ваша ссылка — локальная переменная, то нет, не имеет смысла. Оптимизатор .NET видит момент, когда вашему коду реально больше не нужна ссылка на объект, и может убрать его даже **в середине выполнения** нестатического метода этого самого объекта, если он видит, что `this` больше не используется.

Если же ваша ссылка — поле другого, потенциально долгоживущего объекта, то обнулять её имеет смысл, потому что компилятор не может так просто узнать, нужна ли объекту эта ссылка или нет.

Литература:

- [When does an object become available for garbage collection?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100810-00/?p=13193/)
- [Construction destruction](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/10/construction-destruction/)

Comment: Под обнулением вы подразумеваете присваивание null или вызов Marshal?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Это именно присваивание `null`. Оно работает одинаково вне зависимости от того, у вас там COM-объект или нет.